# how to convert local space rotations to world space in node editor blender?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

i want to convert local space to world space , i managed to convert the location by adding to object location vector
[image]

but when i rotate the object , the textures are changing , how to convert rotations from local to world space ?

Comment: What do you mean by changing? The "usual" way should be, if an object rotates, its texture rotates as well with the object (like object in reality behave), so the texture is not changing relative to the object > which is what your setup does, as long as the object isn't moved anywhere. It changes only when you move it, because then the addition of the location affects the texture.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i don't want the usual way , i don't want the texture to rotate with the object , is there any way i can do that?

Comment: Use _Object_ in the _Texture Coordinate_ node, and choose a different object (e.g. an empty) in the object field to draw the information from, no need for adding.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thankyou , this is exactly what i want.